# What is the most efficient way to use another character instead of a space on a web page?

Tags: html, css

Apologies for the vague title.

**The question: Is there a way with CSS (avoiding JavaScript) to replace spaces with another character without the extra tags?** e.x: `<h1>coming soon</h1>`

Here's an example of what I'd like to improve:
[image: example]

```
<style>
    @import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono';
    @import 'https://justinoboyle.github.io/font/stylesheet.css';
    * {
        font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
    }
    body {
        background-color: #01000f;
    }
    h1 {
        color: #1e88e5;
        font-size: 5vw;
    }
    h1 > endword:before {
        content: "·";
        color: #444444;
    }
    h1 > endword:after {
        content: "⏎";
        margin-left: 1vw;
        color: #444444;
        font-family: "carriagereturn";
    }
</style>

<h1>coming<endword>soon</endword></h1>
```

Thank you in advance, and if there is something that needs clarification, then please let me know in the comments.

Comment: use after and before property of html/css

Comment: @RonakP did you read the question? I am; the question is about using another character in place of a space.

Comment: make one span, apply after. you will get content you need.

Comment: see Harman's answer, i am telling same like him

Comment: Define a font which has a single glyph at the codepoint for the space, then use it.

Comment: @torazaburo this is exactly what I was looking for. Genius! (disappointed I didn't think of it). Thank you! Mind writing this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Will not put up an answer since I really don't know enough about how to create such a font and can't provide the necessary details. The basic concept should work fine of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no completely CSS solutions to this challenge. I have prepared some rather hackish options you could try.

1. With span tags you could use `border-right` or `border-left`. You cannot adjust the height of these because they match the element's dimensions exactly.
2. Use the before and after Pseudo elements

   **HTML:**
       `<h1>Hello</h1> <h1>world</h1>`
      
     **CSS:**
        `h1::after {content: url(dot.png) }`

   The `after` pseudo-element will insert an image (or something else) after the content of the `<h1>`.

Comment: That's fairly similar to what I have, though. I'm fearing that the answer is that I would have to run some JS to turn the traditional markdown into something like you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly, I would suggest using `&nbsp;` in html, which creates whitespaces if thats what you're looking for.

Comment: Not exactly. I'm looking to replace all spaces with a specific character without cluttering up the markup.